# Problems when linking shared library with GCC

Tags: c++, c, gcc, shared-libraries, linker-errors

I try to link a shared library just installed on my system, but for some reason the output doesn't want to execute. This is my compilation:

```
gcc -o test test.c -lgpio
```

When running the output, I get the following error:

```
./test: error while loading shared libraries: libgpio-3.0.0.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Which is weird since I have this exact file in my /usr/local/lib-folder (along with libgpio-3.0.0.so and the other shared library files). I don't have much experience with GCC, so can someone please explain what went wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your library folder is probably not in the default search path.  You'll need to specify it using the `-L` option when you compile:

```
gcc -L /usr/local/lib-folder -o test test.c -lgpio
```

You'll also need to add this folder to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable when you run the program.